# nfcpy - detect a USB-serial connected PN532

Tags: python, macos, nfc

I am trying to use a pn532 board connected using an Adafruit FTDI Friend to my MacBook Pro. It pops up in /dev as "tty.usbserial-XXXXXXXX" (where the Xs are the serial number). I have tried things such as "tagtool.py --device=tty:usbserial-XXXXXXXX:pn532" but no success. I also tried that same connection string straight in my code.

Nfcpy doesn't seem to be detecting the PN532, but it detects my ACR122U over USB just fine. I have already confirmed its not the PN532 board, as libnfc on my Mac detects it, and it works fine on my Raspberry Pi.

My code to connect:

```
with nfc.ContactlessFrontend('tty:usbserial-XXXXXXXX:pn532') as clf:
 tag = clf.connect(rdwr=rdwr_options)
 if tag == False:
     raise KeyboardInterrupt
```

Comment: It can not detect the device since it is connected via a converter. To deyect it, it has to be a real USB device.

Comment: @KlausD. So despite it being (as far as the computer knows) a serial interface, and nfcpy having support for serial interfaces (like the UART on my Pi), it somehow looks at it and specifically says "that's a USB serial converter, I'm gonna ignore it"?

Comment: No, you just have to open the device manually. This of cause requires the converter to be set up and wired properly.

Comment: @KlausD. What do you mean by "open the device manually"? As for the physical hookup, I currently have +5v, GND, TX, and RX on the PN532 board hooked up to their respective counterparts on the FTDI friend.

Comment: For the wiring: that's off topic for SO. For the nfcpy: show us your code!

Comment: @KlausD. I mean, I just want it to work with the examples first. I've edited the question to show my code.

Comment: Unfortunately this points out a missing implementation detail of nfcpy. The internal conversion of a device path does not consider the naming scheme you've said to appear in /dev (simply because I've not yet known about that variant). Please raise this on https://github.com/nfcpy/nfcpy/issues.

Comment: @StephenTiedemann I've opened an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With nfcpy 0.13.0 (and earlier versions) it was not possible to use serial ports on Mac OS X. The `/dev/` naming scheme for OS-X has been added in nfcpy 0.13.1 and those ports are now automatically discovered or specifically selectable with the device path of `nfc.ContactlessFrontend.open()`.

Comment: Thanks for adding this, Stephen! I hadn't had time to summarize our discussion from the GitHub Issue.